# Find all records by the value of the json key in MariaDB 10.1

Tags: mariadb, mysql-json, mariadb-10.1

I have MariaDB 10.1. - I can't use JSON functions - `JSON_EXTRACT` etc.).

In the database I have a table CONTRACTS and a column `data`, which contains JSON (data type TEXT):

```
{"879": "Test", "880": "15255", "881": "2021-10-22"}
```

And I need to find all records that have a key value of `"880"` in some range, eg greater than `10000` and less than `20000`, ie. in this case, a record with a value of `15255`.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Because of [json functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) and [WITH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/) it might be a good idea to upgrade your version of MariaDB

Comment: I edited the title and tags to make it more clear you are using MariaDB. MariaDB is not MySQL, despite being forked from MySQL in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTRACTS.`data`, '"880": "[0-9]+"'), '"[0-9]+"$')
  ) * 1 BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000
FROM
  (SELECT 
   '{"879": "Test", "880": "15255", "881": "2021-10-22"}' AS `data`
  ) AS CONTRACTS
```

So the most internal regexp gives you the key + value. The outer regexp takes that result and extracts the value in quotes. Trim the quotes and test the value. You could use the entire TRIM(...) as a criterium .